# YUI Compressor: Output with line breaks using Ant

Tags: ant, yui-compressor

My Ant build script has this statement:

```
<java
    jar="../tools/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar" fork="true"
    args="../js/navigation.js -o ../js/navigation.min.js">  
</java>
```

The newly created file ../js/navigation.min.js is not formatted. Is there any way by which I can format the populated output file so that it isn't all on one line?

Comment: What do you mean by "not formatted"? What format do you want?

Comment: I mean the populated new file's content appearing in a single line. The total js content is not formatted.

Answer (score 0):

From the [YUI Compressor documentation](https://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/):

```
--line-break
  ...
  Specify 0 to get a line break after each semi-colon in JavaScript, and
  after each rule in CSS.
```

Here's how you would use `--line-break` in an Ant script:

```xml
<java jar="../tools/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar" fork="true">
    <arg value="../js/navigation.js"/>
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg value="../js/navigation.min.js"/>
    <arg value="--line-break"/>
    <arg value="0"/>
</java>
```